# Windows computer does not wake up after being left alone for a few hours (Could be Windows Update)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, crash

I have been having this problem for about a week.

If I leave my Windows 10 Pro computer alone for at least 40 minutes it refuses to come back when I press on the keyboard or mouse.

Instead of getting the lock screen appear nothing changes, the monitor doesn't wake up and it appears that the computer has crashed.

However if I come back within 0-40 minutes the computer will come back fine.

It isn't going to sleep as I have the computer set to max power with no auto sleep settings.

The only way to get the system back is to do a hard reboot via the power button. I have to hold the power button in to do a hard reboot as a single short press does not initiate the computers normal sleep or shutdown cycle.

The computer hardware is a 7th generation Intel Nuc i5.

The only thing that stands out to me is that looking in `Event Viewer` shows the last most entry as `WindowsUpdateClient`.

This just happened to me again. The entry `WindowsUpdateClient` was at 2pm (well before I left the computer). Then there are no logging records at all until I did the hard reboot at 3:26pm.

So it seems the entire computer stalls after `WindowsUpdateClient`.

Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: check whether your disk are turned off after 40 mins. it should be located under power plans. could be a reason with disk. and you can disable windows update from services, then try

Comment: @Joey I had the SSD to stay on always. I have disabled Windows Update from Services, so I will see if that resolves the issue.